# HTML - Is it possible to make a sub-gallery within a gallery?

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I’m messing around with HTML and I wanted to ask if it was possible to make a gallery within a gallery like so...

```
<ul class=‘gallery’>
   <li class=‘image’><img></li>
   <li class=‘image-collection’>
     <ul class=‘sub-gallery’>
       <li class=‘image’><img></li>
       <li class=‘image’><img></li>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Use divs intead of UL LI.
Use sub-gallery div within the gallery div

Comment: If you want you can make it using list item too.

Comment: ok a follow up question, let’s say i have that a gallery and sub gallery div, but in the gallery div, i make each image into a card image, how do i store multiple images into one card (the sub gallery in this case)?

Comment: @JHero23 I think using grid layout will help you. Refer to the below-mentioned link. https://getflywheel.com/layout/card-layout-css-grid-layout-how-to/